# random search optimization tuning

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Можете объяснить для чего нужно random search optimization tuning для decision tree или ссылки на русском. И как это реализовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RandomizedSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) из пакета `Scikit-learn` можно использовать для тюнинга любой модели, не важно `decision tree` это или какая вообще модель. Для дерева просто нужно именно настройки дерева подбирать - например, глубину дерева и прочие такие характеристики. Список параметров и их возможных значений нужно смотреть у конкретной модели, которую вы оптимизируете.

Случайный поиск параметров работает довольно просто - он выбирает случайным образом значения из заданного диапазона для каждого из оптимизируемых параметров, делает это какое-то кол-во раз, а потом проверяет на кросс-валидации, какая метрика получается у модели для каждого из этих случайных наборов параметров. Выбирает лучшую из получившихся метрик и сообщает, с какими параметрами она получилась.

А вот например [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) просто считает метрику по каждому возможному сочетанию параметров (списки значений для каждого параметра указываются вами). Этот поиск возможно точнее, но работает гораздо дольше - нужно перебрать все варианты, а их может быть довольно много. Обычно пользуются всё-таки случайным поиском, потому что он более быстрый, а возможных хороших сочетаний параметров обычно возможно много разных и гнаться за абсолютным максимумом скора обычно нет смысла, достаточно найти хоть какой-то вариант чуть лучший, чем с параметрами, выбранными по умолчанию, либо найденными ручным подбором.

Как реализовать - посмотрите примеры по моим ссылкам. У `Scikit-learn` довольно хорошие примеры в документации. Довольно часто достаточно бывает этих примеров, чтобы во всём разобраться.